# C - Sort Array Desc

Tags: c, arrays

I had several hours thinking in a possible solution to this problem, and I got one but is way too long and I think I made the solution harder than normal.

Can you help me achieve this result in C?

Input (Example):

```
  int input[4] = {40, 10, 50, 23}
  //The solution would be 2, 0, 3 ,1
  input[0] = 40;
  input[1] = 10;
  input[2] = 50;
  input[3] = 23;
```

What I want:

```
int order[4] = {2, 0, 3, 1}
```

By the way I need to maintain the input array so I really need to create other one for the order.

**Edit**:

Well I modified some code and this is working for me, Thx guys.

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (i==j)
            continue;
        if (decimalpart[i]<decimalpart[j])
            ordem[i]++;
    }
}
```

This is working with doubles/floats as well. It wasn't for this concrete example, the array list was random.

Comment: Take an associate array of index and sort that using value of that index in `input` array.

Comment: My solution was like `int order[4] = {0,1,2,3}`, and then change the index to match the solution but it's way to long I guess (the algorithm).

Comment: What's wrong with sorting `int order[4] = {0,1,2,3}` by comparing `input[order[i]]` for element `i`?

Comment: There are tons of sorting algorithms. Have you consulted your favourite algorithms text book or done a web search and then evaluated which one would be suitable for your needs? Doing that is a very instructive learning exercise in itself.

Comment: That's correct, and you would sort order array, but not on the values in order, but the values in input, for example, `if (input[order[x]] > input[order[y]]) swap(x, y);`

Comment: Other way you can use `struct` with `value` and `index` then sort.

Comment: @Exprove - as mentioned, start with int order[4] = {0,1,2,3} , then use qsort with a compare function like mycompare(int *i, int *j){ return (input[*j] - input[*i]) }, to get a descending sort for order.

Comment: http://ideone.com/BBGVSx

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
int i,j;
int input[] = {40, 10, 50, 23};
int size = sizeof(input)/sizeof(int);
int order[size];
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    order[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (i==j) {
            continue;
        }
        if (input[i]>input[j]) {
            order[i]++;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d, ",order[i]);
}
```

Comment: result is not correct when the same value exists in the input.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i know, but he didn't write about how that possibility should be handled, so if he try my code, he will signal back in that case what should the program do.